# get the total number of code lines in python?

Tags: python

I just wanted to know if there is a way to get all the lines of code written and then assign it to a variable and finally print it in python?. I'm trying to make a toy benchmark and I need to calculate the productivity

Comment: Your question needs more details. Are "all the lines of code written" in one module or in multiple files? If multiple files, are they collected into one folder with no other files present? If a single file, is it the file that the code to print the count is in? Are comments and blank lines to be included in the count? And so on.

Comment: It is just a single file, and the comments doesn't need to be included. Generally, as I said, it's a single file and it's a program about the bubble sort with maybe 20 lines including blank lines.

Comment: Saying "the comments doesn't need to be included" is too vague--you need a clear problem statement to write a good program. Are comments and/or blank lines to be included or not? (It is easier to include them). Are docstrings to be considered the same as comments? Is the name of the file (including its path) to be a parameter to the function? Are lines with continuations to be considered as one line or multiple lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short routine to count the number of lines in any text file, not just a program module. This is very simplistic--it counts all lines, including blank lines and comments. Continuation lines are treated as separate lines, multiple statements on one line are counted as only one line, etc. I used an f-string for simplicity, so this requires Python 3.6 or above. The print line can easily be modified for other versions of Python.

```
def count_lines(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        cnt = sum(1 for line in f)
        print(f'There are {cnt} lines in {filename}')
```